# Intergrating wordpress blog in core php site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site in core php (`www.example.com`). I created the `/blogs` directory and installed wordpress in it. 
`www.example.com` has it own login system. In my `www.example.com/blogs` has many blogs and users will come from `www.example.com` . I need to access logged in user info in `www.example.com/blog`s page. So that user dont have to login again in `www.example/blogs` to comment on article. How to do this? Do i need to make custom plugin for this task ?

Answer (score 0):

Just store the cuurent user id in session from www.example.com and access that session in www.example.com/blogs section.

**Note**
 . Use session_start function in wp-config.php file to use $_SESSION variable in wordpress
 . you can use get_userdata( $userid )

Hope this help ;)
Cheers!!!!

Comment: This looks fine , but i am worried about security issue . Is it secure?

Comment: if you are worried about security, then you can use ip based login.
For example - when user logged in from front site, then insert user ip and user_id in wordpress database and retrieve record according to ip.

Comment: and one more thing if you choose database based method, insert expiry time also, that is for how long session will be valid and when user log in, remove previous session record. Hope this helps ;)